# How to get a shell environment variable in a makefile?

Tags: shell, makefile

In shell when I enter

```
echo $demoPath
```

it prints

```
/usr/local/demo
```

How can I get the value of this variable `$demoPath` in a makefile?

Answer (score 303, accepted):

If you've exported the environment variable:

```
export demoPath=/usr/local/demo
```

you can simply refer to it by name in the `makefile` (`make` imports all the environment variables you have set):

```
DEMOPATH = ${demoPath}    # Or $(demoPath) if you prefer.
```

If you've not exported the environment variable, it is not accessible until you do export it, or unless you pass it explicitly on the command line:

```
make DEMOPATH="${demoPath}" …
```

If you are using a C shell derivative, substitute `setenv demoPath /usr/local/demo` for the `export` command.

Comment: "make imports all the environment variables you have set".It works! Nice~,I have no idea about this before,thank you very much.

Comment: @jonathan_leffler I was inspired by your answer and I did something a bit different. I set the envvar before calling make without exporting it: `demoPath=/usr/local/demo make`. You might want to test it out and maybe updating your answer. Cheers!

Comment: @A.D. Yes, that is another mechanism for setting a value for an environment variable for a specific command.  It is slightly tangential to the question which asks how to access the value of an existing variable, rather than how to create one on the fly. It doesn’t stop it being a useful technique on occasion.

Comment: Be careful about some special variables that aren't imported automatically. For example, `$(SHELL)`, which determines what shell `make` uses to execute commands, is initialized to `/bin/sh` rather than the value from the environment.

Answer (score 29):

```
all:
    echo ${PATH}
```

Or change PATH just for one command:

```
all:
    PATH=/my/path:${PATH} cmd
```

Answer (score 29):

for those who want some official document to confirm the behavior

> Variables in make can come from the environment in which make is run.
>   Every environment variable that make sees when it starts up is
>   transformed into a make variable with the same name and value.
>   However, an explicit assignment in the makefile, or with a command
>   argument, overrides the environment. (If the ‘-e’ flag is specified,
>   then values from the environment override assignments in the makefile.

https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Environment.html

Comment: The `-e` hint is gold! But you ommitted an important remark: "But this is not recommended practice" because now *any* variable can be overridden by the environment.

Answer (score 27):

If your `.env` file is located in the same directory you can use `include .env` statement:

**.env**

```bash
DEMO_PATH=/usr/local/demo
```

**Makefile**

```bash
include .env

demo-path:
    echo ${DEMO_PATH}
```

[Read more](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Include.html)

Comment: Could you provide some references to the GNU Make documentation?, will be better in order to dig a little more about the solution.

Comment: this made it work for me on mac. thanks!

Comment: You can also use the syntax `export DEMO_PATH=/usr/local/demo` in the .env file if you want to have a script file you can source in your sh/bash shell as well, like this `. .env`.

Comment: Why isn't this the accepted answer?

Answer (score 16):

if you export the variable in the same script you will need to use two **$$**  instead of $,
if your **Makefile** is looking Something like this:

```
target:
        . ./init.sh; \
        echo ${HOMEPATH}:$${FOO};
```

in **init.sh** script you export the variable FOO

```
$ cat ./init.sh
#!/bin/bash
export FOO=foo:
```

this way when you run make target the env variable **HOMEPATH** that were defined before the script runs will be displayed only using one **$**, but the env variable **FOO** that is exported in **init.sh** script which is executed inside your make file will need **$$** in order to be shown

Answer (score 0):

if you export the variable in the same script you will need to use two $$ instead of $, if your Makefile is looking Somethithis way when you run make target the env variable HOMEPATH that were defined before the script runs will be displayed only using one $, but the e