# Environment variables in Makefile

Tags: makefile

I'm looking through a Makefile for a java project, and can't find any definition for the variable CLASSPATH:

```
JFLAGS = -g -Xlint:unchecked -Xlint:deprecation \
        -sourcepath .. -classpath ..:$(CLASSPATH)

CLASSES = $(SRCS:.java=.class)

...
...
```

Does this refer to an environment variable ('echo $CLASSPATH'  in bash)?

I don't see any references to another Makefile in another directory (e.g. maybe including definitions from a global Makefile?)

Comment: Yes, unless you have overridden it in your makefile.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a shell environment variable in a makefile?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28890634/608639)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Makefiles can indeed reference environment variables, which is exactly what CLASSPATH is in this context. Per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_(Java)),

> Classpath is a parameter in the Java Virtual Machine or the Java
>   compiler that specifies the location of user-defined classes and
>   packages. The parameter may be set either on the command-line, or through an environment variable.

On Linux, you are correct in that you can view the variable with `echo $CLASSPATH`. To set the variable, you can use `export CLASSPATH=/path/to/classfiles`

Comment: excort --> export.