# Make variable that is only passed from the command line

Tags: makefile

I know that I can pass variables to a Makefile in two ways:

`make <target> FOO=bar`

```
export FOO=bar
make <target>
```

and that both of these will make a variable `FOO` available in the makefile with value `bar`.

However, is there a way to require that the variable only comes from the command line? I want the passing of variables to be explicit in order to avoid certain potential overlaps of environment variables, so I want to ensure `make` only receives the variable if passed from the command line, and to disregard it if it's only set in the environment so that the value it uses must be defined by the user when calling `make`.

EDIT: I realize after researching it a bit more that environment variables are not actually accessed the way I thought they are, they're actually used within make as `${FOO}` so as long as I don't define `FOO` at any point in the `makefile`, its only set value will be from the command line (as noted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28891382/1928698)).

Answer (score 3):

These methods to pass variables to GNU make aren't equivalent.

- Variables that come from the environment don't override the assignments in makefile, unless `make` is invoked with `-e` option. See [variables from the environment](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Environment). This is because depending on environment variables is poor practice in terms of build reproducibility (someone forgets to set the environment variable and the build is different):

  > It is not wise for makefiles to depend for their functioning on environment variables set up outside their control, since this would cause different users to get different results from the same makefile. This is against the whole purpose of most makefiles.
- Variables that come from make command line do override assignments in makefile, unless `override` is specified. See [the override directive](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Override-Directive).

Hence, the recommended practice is to explicitly set all your variables to their default values in the makefile unconditionally, so that only the assignments from the command line override them.

Comment: One caveat regarding recommended practice.  The manual also says that  environment variables approach _"is safe for variables with standard or conventional meanings because you know that no makefile will use them for other things."_  It gives example of `CFLAGS`  because _"by setting the variable CFLAGS in your environment, you can cause all C compilations in most makefiles to use the compiler switches you prefer."_  For example you might have several projects that you wish to build in debug mode, so you could simply control this via shell `export CFLAGS="-g3"`.

Comment: @DarrenSmith Not sure if that is still considered good or universally supported practice. Many makefiles just set `CFLAGS := ...` which overrides your environment variable.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there's no difference between `${FOO}` and `$(FOO)`, regardless of the way `FOO` is defined.

If you're using GNU make, there's a function `origin` that allows you to make the distinction: it will return `command line` for a variable defined on the command line and `environment` for a variable exported by the environment (more info in the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Origin-Function.html#Origin-Function))

with the following `Makefile`:

```
foo ?= foo

default:
    @echo ${foo}, comes from $(origin foo)
```

- `make` prints `foo, comes from file`
- `make foo=bla` prints `bla, comes from command line`
- `(export foo=bar; make)` prints `bar, comes from environment`

Answer (score 0):

expanding on @Virgile answer, you could add the following kind of check at the start of the makefile. It is a lot to repeat for each variable you wish to check, although all such checks could reside in a dedicated makefile that is then included from main makefile

```
foo ?= foo

# check origin
ifdef foo
ifneq "$(origin foo)" "command line"
$(error foo: must come from command line)
endif
else
$(error foo not defined)
endif

default:
    @echo ${foo}, comes from $(origin foo)
```