# Have gcc create .s file and executable binary from Makefile

Tags: c, makefile

I am currently learning C with the book "Learn C The Hard Way" and looked into reverse engineering as well. What I want to do is read through the compiler generated assembly for the C programs I have written. I know the option for gcc here is `gcc -S -masm=intel file.c`.

My question now is: can I automatically have gcc create the .s file and the .out file using the Makefile?

My previous Makefiles always looked like this:

```
CC=gcc
CLFAGS=-Wall -g

all: file

clean:
    rm -f file
```

How can I extend my Makefile to make it work?

Comment: https://godbolt.org/ is excellent for disassembly. No icky make files needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like the following:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall -Werror -Wextra -O2 -g
SOURCE=file.c

all: binary assembly

binary: $(SOURCE)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(SOURCE)

assembly: $(SOURCE)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -fverbose-asm -S -masm=intel $(SOURCE)

clean:
    rm -f file.s a.out
```

And use it like this:

```
$ make  # same as `make all`
$ make all  # makes both executable (binary) and assembly
$ make binary  # makes binary file only
$ make assembly  # makes assembly only
```

> It seems that you can execute other labels from other labels. However
> how do they differ from just writing the desired filename like I did?

Remember that `Makefiles` consist of "rules" with the format:

```
target: dependencies
    system command(s)
```

See more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makefile#Rules).

The [`make`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) program decides on what should be done based on how you invoke it and how you define your rules. For example, the first rule with target `all` depends on `binary` and `assembly`, so `make` checks those rules, and carries out the relevant steps (in this case executing `gcc`).

> How does gcc differentiate between them?

The [`gcc`](https://gcc.gnu.org/) program is a compiler, which is a completely separate program. It is merely invoked by `make`, just like `rm` is for the `clean` rule. It has no involvement in processing the `Makefile` itself, so it doesn't need to "differentiate" anything -- `make` does all the processing of the `Makefile`.

> Also, the $() variables you use, do they only exist for gcc or could
> you also define them globally in your operating system?

The variables have nothing to do with `gcc`. The `make` program parses the `Makefile` and performs the necessary substitutions *before* invoking the commands (e.g. `gcc`).

The variables could be used elsewhere in the `Makefile` too, for example with the `rm` command. They are not specific to any command in particular.

You can also make use of environment variables in a `Makefile`, as explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28890634/how-to-get-a-shell-environment-variable-in-a-makefile).

Comment: And `CFLAGS` could have *both* `-O2` and `-g`

Comment: @basile yep I agree, I originally used the OP's choice of CLFAGS flags, but I've updated it now with some important extras

Comment: Thanks! From your answer it seems that you can execute other labels from other labels. However how do they differ from just writing the desired filename like I did? How does gcc differentiate between them?
Also, the $() variables you use, do they only exist for gcc or could you also define them globally in your operating system?

Comment: Also, how do I set the -o flag in the binary label? When I just insert -o test it create both a.out and test

Comment: @bartman1912 glad it helped, see the updated answer in response to your comments

Comment: @bartman1912 adding `-o test` should be enough. Maybe `a.out` is leftover from the previous invocation of `make`? Make sure you `make clean` and then try `make` again. Also don't forget to update the `clean` rule with the correct output file name.

Comment: @costaparas Really thanks a lot! Yes, the a.out was indeed leftover I think and now everything is working perfectly!